# Changing boot loader

Tags: boot

I have dual booted KALI and Ubuntu in my laptop. When the boot starts Kali's boot loader loads to ask which OS to load. I wanted to remove kali. when I did, while booting, the system showed an error saying that the boot loader was not found. I had to reinstall KALI to solve this problem. How can I change the boot loader to Ubuntu's?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall grub by booting a Ubuntu DVD/usb3, mount your instal partitions under /mnt, chroot into / mnt, run grub-install /dev/sda, and set the default os in /etc/grub/defaults.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Comment: Kyle H's link also mentions Boot-Repair which for many users is easier, especially if you cannot boot at all. But you can easily reinstall Ubuntu's grub when booted into Ubuntu if BIOS with just 'sudo grub-install /dev/sda`. That only works from inside your working install.